# press Ctrl+Shift+Del outof firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

So, i need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> in a program way.
I want my extension to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
(to clean all history,cookies,cache and so on).
i do next:

```
var e=document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
e.initKeyEvent( 'keypress', true, true, window, true, false, true, false, 46, 0);
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

According to how i understand, this code has to emulate pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
but nothing happens...document.dispatchEvent(e) happens but the window that is called by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> doesn't appear. Why?

p.s.I know about `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager).removeAll();`
but it's not suitable in my situashion.
i do definetly need to "press" the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
so..any ideas? see mistakes?

Comment: i need it cause this extension is a volunteer computing project.
and we store some system data in user's cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Emulating key press events to start a native function of the browser sounds like a bad, and probably unnecessary, idea.

Why not check out other extensions that clear the cache/history like [**this one**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1801) and check out its [**source code**](http://github.com/choltz/clear-cache-button) to see how it's done.

Comment: see...the problem is that since gecko 1.9 according to developer.mozilla.org/en/nsICookieManager i'm not able to use this:
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsICookieManager).removeAll();

and i need to clear not only cache, but cookies too.
and i got no idea how to solve this problem in another way...

Comment: I see, that's indeed a pickle. Still, keypresses are very unlikely to get you anywhere. There must be some sort of documentation how to clear cookies in a current generation Firefox. Maybe it's worth setting up another question to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

How about opening the popup that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> opens?

Edit: It's `chrome://browser/content/sanitize.xul`. You may also want to have a look at `chrome://browser/content/sanitize.js`.